# How to generate the code coverage report in Jenkins. What extra plugins/Configuration one has to do to get the code coverage

Tags: c, unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage

I'm not able to get the code coverage report in Jenkins for my .net web Api solution even after adding run settings file. In jenkin dashboard its showing empty html table for the report. How will I resolve this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrE5q.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best way to get answers solved is to provide code snippets. Is it possible to show some of your code? Otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: This is related to configuration changes not the code changes in Jenkin!!

Comment: please add more details to your questions, otherwise it is not possible to answer it!